# How to execute java udf without foreach in piglatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a use case and need to call a udf but without using foreach. Is it possible? If yes please elaborate how. Thank you.

Comment: FOREACH is used so that you iterate over all your data and then can call the UDF on each of the row. Curious, whats your use case?

Comment: I also have similar use case. For example, similar to static java function UDFs, I need a UDF which does not have dependency over Tuple etc, which takes some arguments and gives the results e.g. some file paths which I have to load.

Comment: I need to perform a conditional operation for which I am using UDF. Based on the condition the relation gets proper data flow.

Comment: You can call UDF in FILTER  statements as well